# Apache Server Configuration for the Max Concurrent Sessions.

Tags: session, concurrency, apache2.4

I am trying to setup a reverse proxy server with apache2.4. I have an application which sends a request on every 10 sec of an interval.

My Requirement:

Max Concurent Sessions: 10000

Currently, I a using a MPM_EVENT_MODULE.  Below is my configuration.

< IfModule mpm_event_module>

```
    StartServers            3
    MaxRequestWorkers      400
    #MaxClients             400
    ThreadsPerChild         25

    ServerLimit             16
    MinSpareThreads         75
    MaxSpareThreads         250
    #ThreadLimit            64
    MaxConnectionsPerChild   10000
```

< /IfModule>

Whenever I conduct a test most of the connections will go in time wait.
[Screen Shot of server-status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VM6TU.png)

Server Specs: RAM: 32 GB  and CPU core: 16

Please let me know If I ma doing anything wrong with configuration.

Answer (score 0):

MaxRequestWorkers is the important one and you didn't scale it up. You'll need to boost ServerLimit and optionally ThreadLimit/ThreadsPerChild to get MaxRequestWorkers anywhere near 10,000.

Comment: I have tried every possible configuration but I am not able to hit 5000 concurrent sessions. What happens whenever I tried to do test most of the connection will go in time_wait. 

Can you please help me to write the configuration for this? Do I have to change some parameters on the kernel level to achieve the connections?

Answer (score 0):

I have 16 CPU and 64 GB ram and apache server. I did some performance related changes to httpd.conf file and its working very fast now.

```
KeepAlive Off
HostnameLookups Off
<IfModule mpm_event_module>
    ServerLimit 9000
    StartServers 200
    MinSpareThreads 75
    MaxSpareThreads 9000 
    ThreadLimit 64
    ThreadsPerChild 25
    MaxRequestWorkers 9000
    MaxClients 9000
    MaxConnectionsPerChild 1000     
</IfModule>
```

Hope this will help you.